# Get a collection of list <li> tags from html string using Anglesharp

Tags: c#, html, parsing, anglesharp

I am trying to get a list of song titles from a wikipedia page ("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:The_Kinks_songs")

Here is the code I am currently trying

```
//Get page source and parse it
string pageSource = PageSource.Get(url);// own method
HtmlParser parser = new HtmlParser();
var doc = parser.Parse(pageSource);

//Get div tag with class="mw-category"
var div_mw_content_ltr = doc.All.Where(tag => tag.LocalName == "div" && tag.GetAttribute("class") == "mw-category");
//Get all li tags
var li = div_mw_content_ltr.All(tag => tag.LocalName == "li");

List<string> LS = new List<string>();
foreach (var item in div_mw_content_ltr)
    {
        string tmp = item.TextContent;
        LS.Add(tmp);
    }

return LS;
```

I'm really new to this stuff.
var li is false where I expected it to be a collection of the list item tags within the div_mw_content_ltr.

I tried to create a new parser and parse innerhtml of div_mw_content_ltr, but that member does not exist.

I have searched all anglesharp tags on stackoverflow and beyond, but cannot find a solution.
I get the feeling that some underlying knowledge of parsing html and query selectors and such are needed before you can even understand how to use anglesharp, so as a side I'd also appreciate any resource links to where I get get a better understanding of how to actually use the anglesharp library.

Thank you for taking the time to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Issue**

Your `div_mw_content_ltr` is a `IEnumerable<IElement>` since that is what `Where` returns. So using `All` on it is a different method, it just returns true or false if all elements satisfy your condition. It returns false because the only element in the list is the div, it does not recursively return all  elements matching your condition.

---

**To get it to work with LINQ**

Change `Where` to `First` since you are only expecting one, this also allows the use of `Descendents`:

```
var div_mw_content_ltr = doc.All.First(tag => tag.LocalName == "div" && tag.GetAttribute("class") == "mw-category");
```

Instead of `All`, use `Descendents` which returns all descendants of the div and then use `Where` to filter:

```
var li = div_mw_content_ltr.Descendents().Where(tag => tag.NodeName.ToLower() == "li");
```

---

**Query Selectors**

AngleSharp is DOM based so I would use the query selectors `QuerySelector` (first match) or `QuerySelectorAll` (all matches).

The equivalent to the LINQ above would be:

```
var li = doc.QuerySelectorAll("div.mw-category li");
```

`div.mv-category li` means get all `div`s with a css class of `mw-category` and then all `li`s in it.

The syntax for query selectors is basically the [CSS Selector syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Selectors), so it's not something specific to AngleSharp. If you've ever done CSS then this should be familiar.

And if you haven't already, read the [wiki](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp/wiki) for AngleSharp.

Comment: Excellent answer, somehow comprehensive and concise concurrently. I appreciate your time, thank you.  And thanks for the link, too.